# Dodging error bars in marginsplot in Stata

Tags: graphics, stata

I am using `marginsplot` to draw some error bars between two different groups. The error bars overlap though, so I'm trying to dodge them slightly left-or-right from one another.

Here is an example slightly edited from the `marginsplot` help that illustrates the problem:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/nhanes2
quietly regress bpsystol agegrp##sex
quietly margins agegrp#sex
marginsplot, recast(scatter) ciopts(recast(rspike))
```

[image]

Is there any easy way to dodge the blue `Male` points and bars slightly to the left, and the red `Female` points and bars slightly to the right (or vice-versa)? Like what is done is dodged bar charts.

Here it would work out fine to recast the confidence intervals to an area and make it slightly transparent as in the help example further down the line. However, for my actual use I would like to keep the points and spikes.

Comment: I think adding tails can help with this somewhat: `marginsplot, recast(scatter) ciopts(recast(rcap))`

Comment: You might also try the horizontal option which flips X and Y axes. There is an example in the help manual.

Comment: Horizontal does not help with this problem Imo. The tails help alittle @Dimitriy V. Masterov, but the main problem remains and are not as effective as simply dodging them slightly left/right would be. (I find the end caps distracting almost always, so I tend to just do the lines.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach using the *community-contributed* commands `parmest` and `eclplot`.

The trick is to adjust the values of the group variable by a small amount, for example `0.1`, and then to use the `subby` option of `eclplot`:

```
** a short version
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/nhanes2
qui reg bpsystol agegrp##sex
qui margins agegrp#sex
qui parmest , bmat(r(b)) vmat(r(V)) level( `cilevel' ) fast
qui split parm, parse( . # )
qui destring parm*, replace
replace parm1 = parm1 - ( 0.05 )
eclplot estimate min95 max95 parm1, eplot(sc) rplottype(rspike) supby(parm3, spaceby(0.1))
```

[image: short version]

However, the problem with this approach is that all the labels get lost but I do not know of a good way to retrieve them, other than by brute force.

The following is an extended version of the code where I tried to automate re-application of all the value labels by a brute force method:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/nhanes2, clear

** specify parameters and variables
local cilevel = 95
local groupvar agegrp
local typevar sex
local ytitle "Linear Prediction"
local title "Adjust Predictions of `groupvar'#`typevar' with `cilevel'% CIs"
local eplot scatter
local rplottype rspike
local spaceby 0.1 /* use this param to control the dodge */

** store labels of groupvar ("agegrp") and typevar ("sex")
local varlist `groupvar' `typevar'
foreach vv of var `varlist' {
    local `vv'_varlab : var lab `vv'        
    qui levelsof `vv', local( `vv'_vals )
    foreach vl of local `vv'_vals {     
        local `vv'_`vl'lab : lab `vv' `vl'  
        lab def `vv'_vallab `vl' "``vv'_`vl'lab'", add
    }
}

** run analysis
qui reg bpsystol `groupvar'##`typevar'
margins `groupvar'#`typevar'

** use parmest to store estimates
preserve
parmest , bmat(r(b)) vmat(r(V)) level( `cilevel' ) fast
lab var estimate "`ytitle'"

split parm, parse( . # )
qui destring parm*, replace
rename parm1 `groupvar'
rename parm3 `typevar'

** reaply stored labels
foreach vv of var `varlist' {
    lab var `vv' "``vv'_varlab'"
    lab val `vv' `vv'_vallab
}

** dodge and plot
replace agegrp = agegrp - ( `spaceby' / 2 )
eclplot estimate min95 max95 agegrp ///
    , eplot( `eplot' ) rplottype( `rplottype' ) ///
    supby( sex, spaceby( `spaceby' ) ) ///
    estopts1( mcolor( navy ) ) estopts2( mcolor( maroon ) ) ///
    ciopts1( lcolor( navy ) ) ciopts2( lcolor( maroon ) ) ///
    title( "`title'" )

restore
```

[image: Dodged Error Bar Chart Manually]

Comment: I was thinking of more simply restoring the results of `margins` in a matrix after the command, e.g. `matrix results = r(table)`. From there you can do the necessary data manipulation to make the dodged error bar plot.

Comment: Gracias. That's what I thought to do initially, but couldn't find a simpler way to go from a matrix to an error bar plot. What `parmest` does is essentially the same: it automates the process of storing estimates and computes confidence intervals from `r(b)` and `r(V)`. Unfortunately, it loses the variable and value labels when doing so; half of the code above is just trying to automate the process of reapplying the original variable and value labels to the stored estimates. I edited the answer to attach a version of the code without all the labeling to clarify what I mean.